# BouncyCastle Provider Jar causes Java Heap Space Error

Tags: java, android, ssl, out-of-memory, bouncycastle

Has Anyone run into this problem?

I am trying to use BouncyCastle to Create Certificate in Android but as soon as I have added BouncyCastle Provider Jar, I get Java Heap Space problem, Eclipse crashes with OutOfMemory error.

All I am doing is following, which is similar to Example code in bouncy castle,

```
public static X509Certificate createMasterCert(
    PublicKey pubKey,
    PrivateKey privKey)
    throws Exception
{
    //
    // signers name
    //
    String issuer = "C=AU, O=The Legion of the Bouncy Castle, OU=Bouncy Primary Certificate";

    //
    // subjects name - the same as we are self signed.
    //
    String subject = "C=AU, O=The Legion of the Bouncy Castle, OU=Bouncy Primary Certificate";

    //
    // create the certificate - version 1
    //
    X509v1CertificateBuilder v1CertBuilder = new JcaX509v1CertificateBuilder(
        new X500Name(issuer),
        BigInteger.valueOf(1),
        new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30),
        new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)),
        new X500Name(subject),
        pubKey);

    X509CertificateHolder cert = v1CertBuilder.build(new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider(BC).build(privKey));

    return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(BC).getCertificate(cert);
}
```

Comment: could you show us your eclipse.ini?

Comment: -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.mobile.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m

Comment: see my answer and restart your eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code is being executed in Android, increasing Eclipse's heap size will do nothing for you, because it simply has nothing to do with it. The heap size of Android applications is fixed and you cannot increase it (not before Honeycomb anyway). What version of Android are you using? Additionally, the BouncyCastle libraries are part of Android, so even if you add them to your project, it will use the system ones, which are slightly different and this can lead to subtle (and not so subtle) errors. IF you want to use BC on pre-Honeycomb (3.0) platforms you need to change the package name or include Spongy Castle which already does this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried using spoungycastle. Unfortunately I hit the same wall again. Any idea if there is another way to generate certificate on Android or add one per installation externally?

Comment: Also, I need to support android version 2.2 and above so I guess I am stuck with external library. However, just from a knowledge perspective, I did not see if I can create a cert using bouncycastle within android, without external jar...

Comment: You need to use an external library on any version of Android, because  BC is not part of the SDK. Not sure why you are getting an out of memory error, does this code work in a desktop application?

Comment: Yes, the code library is also used in the backend .net and it is very common across platform. I tried executing one sample project which SpoungyCastle has provided for Android [link](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle-eclipse/), and I ran into same problem

Comment: What device are you running on? Does it work on other devices?

Comment: I tried on emulator with OS version 4.0.3 also on my phone with 4.0.4 and few other emulatros and machines, still getting same thing. Anyways, I will post the solution here as soon as I find it.

Comment: This works fine on Galaxy Nexus running 4.1.2 using the latest Spongy Castle libraries (just replaced "BC" in your code with "SC").

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I am still trying to figure out what am I doing wrong. Probably I will find some silly issue. :)

Comment: Hi Nikolay, Just a quick question, which ADT version are you using? It seems that the problem might be in eclipse and ADT versions which causes unhandled event look exception with GC Overhead limit reached.... I will investigate...

Comment: ADT 21 latest beta. To rule out Eclipse, export your app to an APK, shut down Eclipse and install via adb.

Comment: I built it with ant, same code and it worked. With Eclipse I didnt have any luck, so I believe its something with eclipse that I might be using is the issue... For reference I have Eclipse Indigo with ADT 20.0.3

Comment: Creating a new workspace sometimes helps. You may also want to update your JDK.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the heap space follow these steps:

1. Right Click on your project in Package Explorer and go to Run As and click Run Configuration and find the name of your class.
2. In the Arguments tab(next to Main tab) inside the box labeled VM arguments write `-mx256m`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect something is wrong with the program e.g. long loop, high memory need or so..Not aware of the jar so unable to comment.

If you want to run eclipse with increased heap, run the command below to start the eclipse:

```
    eclipse [normal arguments] -vmargs -Xmx512M
```

set the size as per your need.

Alternatively, you can open `eclipse.ini` under your `eclipse` root directory and update the vmargs param:

```
  .......
  -vmargs
  -Xms40m
  -Xmx512m <---Update this value
```

Once done, restart the eclipse.

Comment: Is anyone of you aware if this jar has some problem itself, as if I remove this jar then all works great, however to generate a certificate for SSL I am dependent on it,

Comment: Not aware of this jar(I mentioned that as the first statement) but if you increase your heap by little value and it runs fine it means, your eclipse was running on threshold heap. If still fails, means the jar has problem.

Comment: Thanks, I tried updating heap space but still stuck, So I believe its a jar problem :(

Comment: I am positive its JAR issue as in the code, I don't see any looping or recursion so don`t think your program code(share) is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
```

to

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
```